# make proto in micro project throws error Expected "{" in windows 10

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, go-micro

Starting with [micro](http://%20https://github.com/micro/micro) and everything works fine. I dont have VisualStudio,  but instead I have `make` through [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/)(dont know if could be the issue)

I bootstrap the service with `micro new` like this.

```
λ micro new my.test
Creating service my.test

.
├── micro.mu
├── main.go
├── generate.go
├── handler
│   └── my.test.go
├── proto
│   └── my.test.proto
├── Dockerfile
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── .gitignore
└── go.mod


download protoc zip packages (protoc-$VERSION-$PLATFORM.zip) and install:

visit https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases

download protobuf for micro:

go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/proto
go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go
go get github.com/micro/micro/v3/cmd/protoc-gen-micro

compile the proto file my.test.proto:

cd my.test
make proto
```

Installed dependencies and everything was fine. Then I moved to my.test and after `make proto` this error shows up

```
protoc --proto_path=. --micro_out=. --go_out=:. proto/proto.test.proto
proto/proto.test.proto:7:14: Expected "{".
make: *** [Makefile:16: proto] Error 1
```

I have all dependencies and my PATH is fine, but I dnt know what  the problem is.

Edit: This is my proto, conveniently generated by micro

```
syntax = "proto3";

package proto.test;

option go_package = "./proto;proto.test";

service Proto.Test {
    rpc Call(Request) returns (Response) {}
    rpc Stream(StreamingRequest) returns (stream StreamingResponse) {}
    rpc PingPong(stream Ping) returns (stream Pong) {}
}

message Message {
    string say = 1;
}

message Request {
    string name = 1;
}

message Response {
    string msg = 1;
}

message StreamingRequest {
    int64 count = 1;
}

message StreamingResponse {
    int64 count = 1;
}

message Ping {
    int64 stroke = 1;
}

message Pong {
    int64 stroke = 1;
}
```

Comment: @CeriseLimón yes, thank you. Please read my answer and tell me if you know the why. And thanks for the quick answer for my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go package names cannot contain dots - it will just not compile:

```
$ cat pkg.go

package dot.test

$ go build

./pkg.go:1:12: syntax error: unexpected .
```

so one has to ensure generated code produces a valid Go package name.

---

From the `Go spec`, the [package clause](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_clause) is defined as:

> A package clause begins each source file and defines the package to
> which the file belongs.

```
PackageClause  = "package" PackageName .
PackageName    = identifier .
```

and an [identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Identifiers) as:

> ... a sequence of one or more letters and digits. The first
> character in an identifier must be a letter.

```
identifier = letter { letter | unicode_digit } .
```

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

After some reading of the basics I found the problem. Even if the proto file is generated by micro this code `service Proto.Test`  at line seven is the problem, because of the dot. I mean, replacing that for  `service Test`  solved the issue. Now I dont know why. Any explanation would be preciated. I am in windows by the way